# Chart.js Disappear on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `Chart.js` to display a line chart in a div which is within a `<tr>`.

```
<tr class="item">...</tr>
<tr class="item-details">
...
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 chart-pane">
        <div class="chart-container">
            ...
            <div><canvas id="future-chart"></canvas></div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</tr>
```

When the page is loaded, the `item-details` `<tr>` is hidden, and clicking on the `item` `<tr>` above it will make it show as well as call a function to draw the chart in the canvas.  This function is shown below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    var itemDetails = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
    ...
    var canvas = itemDetails.find('#future-chart').get(0);

    if (canvas) {
        ...
        // just setting data here
        var data = { 
            ...
        };
        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true
        };  
        var futureChart = new Chart(context).Line(data,options);
    }   
});
```

The problem I'm having is that if I click the div to show when the screen is larger than 767px (), then click again to hide, resize the screen to less than 767px, and open the tr again, the chart is gone.

This is the only case I can find which makes the chart disappear.  If I do the opposite of the above, the chart stays there.  If I leave the `<tr>` open and resize the window, the chart stays just fine.

I have `Responsive` set to *True* and the chart resizes correctly when the `<tr>` is open and I resize the window.

I was thinking I needed to re-draw the canvas when the window is resized, however the entire chart is supposed to be re-drawn whenever the `<tr>` is opened, so I'm not sure exactly what is causing this.

Comment: What happens when you `Inspect Element`? Is the chart still in your DOM? I'm wondering if the issue is that it's giving it a size of 0 because it's sizing the chart according to the parent div and when `tr` is hidden, it's size is 0. Since opening the `tr` element doesn't trigger a `window.resize` event, it doesn't redraw the chart. Does resizing the window after you open the `tr` give you a correctly sized chart once again?

Comment: The chart is still in the DOM, and it has a width depending on the size of the window, however the height is set to`0`.  Resizing the window after opening the `tr` always gives a correctly sized chart except for the one case.

Comment: I tried setting a min-height on the canvas, so now the height is always `> 0`, but the canvas area is still empty.

Comment: an external link to the online version is really the only case you may find your answer

Comment: Realize this is an old question, however: I ran into trouble with window resizing and charts (Chart.js 2.7.2) disappearing, which I resolved by calling `chart.update()` after a resize event.  Have you tried this?

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem, on resizing the window, the graph disappears.
I solved the problem by creating the graph just once with the new command

```
this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'line', .....
}
```

After that, I only do `update()` on the created chart. indeed, creating a chart each time is not kept in memory.
Example to update the `datasets`

```
this.myChart.data.datasets = datasetsTmp;
this.myChart.update();
```

I hope it's help.

Answer (score -2):

You need to fetch the data between two dates, every time user resize the graph

See the [coinmarketcap.com](https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/1516240463000/1516326863000/)